# Remove last / of path string using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I'm trying to use sed to replace just the last / in the following directory structure, but I'm not able to succeed with this. Any suggestions?

Input is `/tmp/ABC/Dirs/`, output should be `/tmp/ABC/Dirs`

```
echo " /tmp/ABC/Dirs/"  | sed -r "s/\/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9])/g"
```

Comment: @Alex Comments are transient, leave an answer!

Comment: If you're doing this to "clean up" a pathname so that it doesn't confuse the shell, it's not necessary.  shells don't get confused by extra `/` characters.  `//////path/to///somewhere///filename` is just `/path/to/somewhere/filename` as far as the shell is concerned.   BTW, `readlink`'s `-e` and `-f` options can be used to canonicalise a pathname to a directory or file (i.e. resolve all symlinks and return the canonical pathname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was the one who answered the question first with my `s/\/$//` comment.

Other people had time to contribute much fuller answers that day.

SO today -a few days later- I post a redundant answer, because I want the "Peer Pressure" Bronze award gone from the list.

```
sed -e s./$..g   # You can golf the quotes and the "\" here
```

So please, good folks, please downvote this time until -3 :)

Comment: What? No! This was supposed to be a troll answer, meant to be down-voted, so that I could delete It at `-3` to get the "Peer Pressure" Bronze award. You foiled that plan by marking mine as the AA. ;)     The answers below e.g. from @Stephane are much more comprehensive. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 8):

`sed` seems to be rather overkill here, you can remove a trailing `/` directly in the Korn shell (and similar shells like `bash`, and all POSIX compliant shells as that Korn shell feature has been specified by POSIX for the `sh` utility):

```
$ foo=/tmp/ABC/Dirs/
$ echo "${foo%/}"
/tmp/ABC/Dirs
```

Comment: Thanks for help, worked perfectly. Think this one will be sufficient for my scenario. I was trying more with sed.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to do with with `sed`, you'd do:

```
file=/any/path
sed '$s|/$||' << EOF
$file
EOF
```

That is, remove a `/` character at the end (second `$`) of the last (first `$`) line of the path stored in `$file`. With some `sed` implementations that assumes the size in bytes of the greatest sequence of non-newline characters in `$file` doesn't exceed `LINE_MAX` (which is often shorter than the maximum size of a path supported in arguments to system calls).

Note that for the special case of `/` or `//`, stripping that trailing `/` may not be desirable. You may also want to remove all trailing `/` in `/foo/bar///` for instance.

So maybe a more *advanced* one and that would justify `sed` a bit more would be:

```
sed '
  ${
    s|\([^/]\)/*$|\1|
    s|^////*|/|
    1b
    s|/*$||
  }' << EOF
$file
EOF
```

That is preserve `//` as it is, turn `///`, `/////` and `/` into `/`, but `foo//` into `foo` and `$'foo\n//'` into `$'foo\n'`.

Note that `(?:...)` is a perl regexp operator, not extended regexp operator (as recognised by GNU `sed` with that GNU-specific `-r` option).

Answer (score 1):

You can use perl instead of sed:

```
echo "/tmp/ABC/Dirs/" | perl -pne  "s/\/$//g"
```

Output

```
/tmp/ABC/Dirs
```

Comment: You can golf this to `perl -pne s./$..g`